# Mojarra findComponent return null for valid id when inside composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have a custom component that look as follow

```
<custom:container>
    <custom:checkbox index="0"/>
    <custom:checkbox index="1"/>
</custom:container>
```

so when encodeBegin first call, it will show hit the tag `<custom:container>`, and it will try to save this component cliend id,

```
private String containerClientId;
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component){
    if (component instanceof ManyCheckboxContainer) {            
        containerClientId = component.getClientId(context);
        return; 
    }
}
```

so encodeEnd get called when I hit `<custom:checkbox index="0"/>`, like this

```
public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {

    ...

    if (component instanceof Checkbox) {
        renderCheckbox(context, (Checkbox) component);
    } 
    ...
}

protected void renderCheckbox(FacesContext facesContext, InforRadio radio) throws IOException {
    ...
    UIComponent uiComponent = radio.findComponent(containerClientId);
    if(uiComponent == null){
         //throw error
    }
    ...
}
```

If I DO NOT have this custom component inside composite component then everything work great, but once I put it in a composite component, `radio.findComponent(containerClientId);` return `null`. Is this a bug in mojarra? I test this under 2.1.10 and 2.1.11, same behavior.

**EDIT**
So I take that back, this behavior happen when my custom component is inside two nested `NamingContainer`, so something like this

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <f:subView id="myView">
        <custom:container id="myCustom">
            <custom:checkbox index="0"/>
            <custom:checkbox index="1"/>
        </custom:container>
    </f:subView>
</h:form>
```

so in this case the client id (that return by `component.getClientId(context)`) for `<custom:container>` is `myForm:myView:myCustom`, but inside Mojarra, the `findComponent` method has this

```
public UIComponent findComponent(String expr) {
     ...

     else if (!(base instanceof NamingContainer)) {
     // Relative expressions start at the closest NamingContainer or root
     while (base.getParent() != null) {
         if (base instanceof NamingContainer) {
             break;
         }
         base = base.getParent();
     }
     ...
}
```

so it looks for the next ancestor `NamingContainer`, which in my case is the `f:subView` not the `h:form`. It then parse the client id, loop through it, each time passing piece of the id to the `UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent base, String id, boolean checkId)`. So the first time in, this method take `form3` as id and current UIComponent is f:subView, it search for all its facets and children to see if any component match `form3`, of course, none will match since `form3` is the parent of `f:subView` in my structure. So `null` is return. Is this Mojarra bugs or am I doing some wrong. I thought that the client id is relative from the next NamingContainer ancestor instead of all the way to the root of the NamingContainer? Am I wrong on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) it seems to me that Mojarra got it right.

According to the docs you should place a seperator (a colon) in front of your search expression if you want to do an "absolute" search from the root of your tree.
Otherwise it will do a relative search from the component itself if it is a NamingContainer or the first parent that is a NamingContainer.

BTW: The docs I linked to appear to be the same as the official docs distributed with the specs. Official specs are [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314).

Comment: However, I feel that `component.getClientId(context);` should return the client Id with `:` in front of it.